# Prove Bayesian Updating

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I've started learning Bayesian analysis and for a past few days I'm struggling with proving what seems to be obvious to every author of each literature I read. The question is:

### **How is Bayesian update justified mathematically?**

To explain the question, let me describe a classical example. Assume there is a disease which infects around 1% of a total population. Also, there is a test which has 95% recall and 99% precision. Let variable $\theta$ describe if some person is affected: 1 if yes and 0 if no. Then we may specify the next probabilities:
$$ P(\theta=1) = 0.01 \mathrm{~ - Prior},$$
$$ P(y=1 |\theta=1)=0.95  \mathrm{~ - Likelyhood}, ~ P(y=0|\theta=0)=0.99, $$
where $y$ is a variable describing a test result of the person: 1 if positive and 0 otherwise. Using the Bayesian rule we may now calculate our *measure of uncertainty about whether*
(a.k.a. *probability of*) this person is affected or not, given that its first test result is positive. E.g.: $y_1 = 1$. We have:
$$P(\theta=1|y_1=1) \mathrm{~ - Posterior } = {{P(\theta=1) P(y_1=1|\theta=1)} \over {P(y_1=1)} \mathrm{~ - Marginal}} = {{P(\theta=1) P(y_1=1|\theta=1)} \over {\int P(\theta) P(y_1=1|\theta)d\theta} } = $$
$$ ={{P(\theta=1) P(y_1=1|\theta=1)} \over {P(\theta=1)P(y_1=1|\theta=1) + P(\theta=0)P(y_1=1|\theta=0)}} = {{0.01 \cdot 0.95} \over {0.01 \cdot 0.95 + 0.99 \cdot 0.01}} \approx 0.49.$$

This makes a lot of sense. If there are 1000 persons tested, we expect only around 10 to be affected. 9 out of those 10 (95%) and 9 out of rest 990 (1%) would yield positive result. So its approximately $9 \over 18$ - affected to all the positive.

*Now the magic part.*

All the literature I found regarding the above example state, that if the person makes a second test and gets it positive too ($y_2=1$), then there is no need to recalculate the entire thing. Rather we may just use the posterior distribution above as a prior to update our measure. And this is done like this:
$$P(\theta=1|y_1=1,y_2=1) = {{P(\theta=1|y_1=1) P(y_2=1|\theta=1)} \over {P(y_2=1)}} = {{P(\theta=1 |y_1=1) P(y_2=1|\theta=1)} \over {\int P(\theta|y_1=1) P(y_2=1|\theta)d\theta} } = $$
$$ ={{P(\theta=1|y_1=1) P(y_2=1|\theta=1)} \over {P(\theta=1|y_1=1)P(y_2=1|\theta=1) + P(\theta=0|y_1=1)P(y_2=1|\theta=0)}} = {{0.49 \cdot 0.95} \over {0.49 \cdot 0.95 + 0.51 \cdot 0.01}} \approx 0.98.$$
The above calculations make a lot of sense too. Since, approximately 9 out of first positive 9s would yield a second positive result, while most likely 0 out of second positive 9s would yield second positive too. So this time this is approximately $9 \over 9$ - affected to both positive. But this calculation is only valid if
$$P(\theta|y_1,y_2) = {{P(\theta|y_1) P(y_2|\theta)} \over {\int P(\theta|y_1) P(y_2|\theta) d\theta}}.~~~~~~~\mathrm{(1)} $$

However, I can't prove the above (and not even sure if this is true) nor straightforward, nor relying on observables *iid* (independent and identically distributed $y$'s) given $\theta$.

### *TL;DR*

Prove (1). If needed, rely on independence or conditional independence (given $\theta$) of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: In the Bayesian paradigm, by an  i.i.d  sample $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ it is meant that given $\theta$,  $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent. In terms if densities, if the sample $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ are drawn from distributions with densities given $theta$, then the joint distribution given $\theta$ has destiny given by $\boldsymbol{f}(y_1,\ldots,y_n|\theta)=f(y_1|\theta)\cdot\ldots\cdot f(y_n|\theta)$. Thus, the posterior distribution given $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is of the form $\pi(\theta|y_1,\ldots y_n)\propto f(y_1|\theta)\cdot\ldots\cdot f(y_n|\theta)\pi(\theta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An (arguably more general) form of Bayes rule is

$$P(x|y,z) = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x|z)}{P(y|z)}$$

where every term is conditioned on some other variable $z$. In your problem, we would condition everything on $y_1$, yielding:

$$P(\theta | y_1,y_2) = \frac{P(y_2|y_1,\theta)P(\theta|y_1)}{P(y_2|y_1)}$$

We can use $P(y_2|y_1) = \int P(y_2|y_1,\theta)P(\theta|y_1)d\theta$ to substitute on the bottom to get

$$P(\theta | y_1,y_2) = \frac{P(y_2|y_1,\theta)P(\theta|y_1)}{ \int P(y_2|y_1,\theta)P(\theta|y_1)d\theta}$$

The key argument from here is that $y_2$ is independent of $y_1$, conditional on $\theta$. In this example, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not independent, because if you have one positive test, that increases your probability that you are affected, which in turn increases your estimate that a *second* test will also come up positive. But, if you already know whether or not you are affected (i.e., you are conditioning on $\theta$), then we assume the outcome of the second test will be independent. This means that $P(y_2|y_1,\theta)=P(y_2|\theta)$.

Substituting that in the above gives the result:

$$P(\theta | y_1,y_2) = \frac{P(y_2|\theta)P(\theta|y_1)}{ \int P(y_2|\theta)P(\theta|y_1)d\theta}$$

If you haven't seen the more general form of Bayes rule that I started with, I can think of two reasonably good justifications.

The first would be that the rules of probability ought to let us incorporate more information into *all* of our terms without impacting the overall reasoning. For example, suppose you read a study which shows that the precision is slightly different than 99%. If we let $z$ represent that information (i.e., the event of "a study came out claiming ..."), then the *structure* of your reasoning shouldn't need to change, only the numerical values.

The second would be that if we take a random variable like $\theta$, and condition on an event like $(y_1=1)$, this gives us another random variable $\theta | (y_1=1)$. We can just "substitute" this new random variable in Bayes' rule (please convince yourself that conditioning on $\theta |y_1=1$ is the same as conditioning on $\theta,y_1=1$).

Finally, we can just derive it from the product rule by first treating $y,z$ as a single variable, then treating $x,z$ as a single variable, then treating them as separate variables:
$$\begin{align}
P(x|y,z) = & \frac{P(x,y,z)}{P(y,z)}\\
= & \frac{P(x,z)P(y|x,z)}{P(y,z)}\\
=& \frac{P(z)P(x|z)P(y|x,z)}{P(z)P(y|z)}\\
=& \frac{P(x|z)(y|x,z)}{P(y|z)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer. Thank